# p.classname or .classname p, any difference?

Tags: css, class, css-selectors

So, I am a bit confused over this simple thing, i've googled as much as i could, but i just dont know the right keywords for googling it, i tried CSS selectors, etc, no answer was enough to clear my confusion. So i've also tested and p.classname doesn't even seem to work, but by definition in a book i'm reading ( updated 2012 )

To create a class in CSS and select an element in that class, you write a
class selector, like this:

```
p.classname{ stuff }
```

So now you have a way of selecting

elements that belong to a certain class to
style them.

I couldn't find a definition for

`classname p`, but myself would give something like this definition "select all p elements that belong to classname", which is basicly the same.

the `p.classname` works when i give the "classname" to a  im still confused, at the moment i would suppose im just going to perma use the .classname p, which works and is basically the same.

So, please help me out to clear this confusion, i've googled, i tried to help this confusion but it didn't work, it only made more.

Thanks

Comment: Here we don't put "SOLVED" on the title, we select the answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So when you do

```
p.classname{
  ... 
}
```

You are looking for a `<p>` with class `classname`

when you do

```
.classname p
```

You are looking for a `p`  that is a descendant of the classes `classname`.

In CSS `.` is used as a selector for a class name.

Comment: `.classname p` means you are looking for a `p` that's a descendant of any `.classname`.

Comment: I think posting helped me out to regroup ideas, but then if i really get it, i would say p.classname is kind of bad, as you have to put all the time the same classname inside a paragraph... So this way is good for multiple locations inside of different divs while .classname p is good if you want to style all P inside one div?

Comment: `in the subclass of classes by the name classname` head spinning trying to understand this :D

Comment: @EliasZan: Neither are good or bad.  It depends what you want to do.  You can have *multiple* elements with the same class.  It all depends on what you are doing.

Comment: CSS parsin is right to left. So if p selector is not needed `.classname` is enough. Again, depends on the use

Comment: @Ejay - Stop spinning your head and reload the page

Comment: @Elias - since class names are not unique, by doing `p.classname`, you are explicitly restricting the properties to `p` tag that have a class of `classname`

Comment: @karthikr You've cured me, master! :D

Comment: yea i believe maybe i finally start to see the purposes of using such thing, by the way, if i wanted to google over this what keyword would i need? selectors css didn't seem to be enough, i find sites that either explain one or the other one, not both at once

Comment: Thanks everyone who answered, im not sure to who and how im supposed to tell how to close it because i get it now.

Comment: You close by accepting an answer. The green tick next to an answer is how you accept

Comment: @karthikr thanks, kinda a bad system in a way, say multiple guys provided good answers i'll be able to reward only one...!

Comment: I agree with you.  you can upvote all the answers you like though

Answer (score 2):

CSS works by reading each rule in order, example.

```
p {font-weight: bold;}

p span {font-weight:normal;}

<p>Hiya</p> // BOLD

<p><span>HIYA</span></p> // NORMAL
```

Same goes for classes

```
.bold {font-weight: bold;}

span {font-weight:normal;}

<p class="bold">I AM BOLD <span>I AM NOT</span> BOLD AGAIN</p>

<p class="bold"><span> I AM ALL NORMAL</span></p>
```

So in your example defining a `class` first will target each and every element that has that class.

By defining something after that class `.class p` it will target all elements inside that class which are p.

Hope this helped

**UPDATE**

so you can understand better,

```
div {color: blue;}
div p {color: red;}
div p span {color: yellow;}
div ul {color: purple;}

<div>I AM BLUE <p>I AM RED <span> I AM YELLOW</span></p>I AM BLUE</div>

<p>I HAVE NO CSS ATTACHED TO ME</p>

<div><ul><li>I AM PURPLE</li></ul> I AM BLUE</div>
```

It works exactly the same for classes as it does with elements.

Comment: Yeah, ok i think maybe i finally get it, as i said before, if i have 5 divs in a page and they all have a blue paragraph, i call a class "blue" and do this : p.blue { color:blue; } and it will only select those 5 element with such class, while i would need to do changes for each div if i needed to make 5 paragraphs blue with "class p", but then, if i do div1 p.blue {color:blue;} ( is it even possible? im going to try after i post anyway ) i assume only div1 p.blue will become blue, right?

Comment: Yes, you can select only one element like that too, but an id would be better for such a use. I will extend my answer to help you understand more, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I would explain it like this,
if you have the following CSS below:

`p.classname { stuff }`

it has locked that class name to the `<p>` tags only.

So if you put `class="classname"` in anything else, it won't work on anything but the `<p>` tags.